# Immutable value as inout argument

Tags: swift, pointers, inout

I would like to have a pointer as a parameter of a class. But when I am trying to code the init, I am having this error: `Cannot pass immutable value of type 'AnyObject?' as inout argument`

```
class MyClass {
    var valuePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>

    init(value: inout AnyObject?) {
        self.valuePointer = &value
    }
}
```

I would like to create some instance of MyClass which can all refer to the same "value". Then, when I am editing this value in this class, it would change everywhere else.

This is the first time I'm working with pointer in Swift. I guess I am doing it wrong...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For those who has the `cannot pass immutable value as inout argument` error. Check that your argument is not optional first. Inout type doesn't seems to like optional values.

Comment: This fixed my problem on Linux Swift. Thanks! 
The full error message:
_error: cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion **from '[String : Any?]' to '[String : Any?]?'** requires a temporary_
should have tipped me off: by changing the signature inout parameter to [String: Any], the compiler didn't complain anymore.

Comment: You can just make a copy with a new variable and it will work with an optional fyi

Answer (score 3):

You could send the pointer when initializing the object:

```
class MyClass {
    var valuePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>

    init(value: inout UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>) {
        self.valuePointer = value
    }
}
```

Just add the pointer reference when initializing `MyClass`:

```
let obj = MyClass(value: &obj2)
```

Comment: Thanks @andriosr, I tried that but then I have another issue when I initializing my class: `Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>'`. I am doing: `let obj = MyClass(value: &firstName)`(which is a String?). I don't see why...

Comment: I think I found my answer. Apparently I have to cast it first. It isn't as simple as adding a `&` before... Here is the code I found: `UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>(((firstName)! as NSString).utf8String!))`

Comment: Thats great! Please, post it yourself or let me know if you want me update my answer with this resolution so others can take advantage of it :)

Comment: I already accepted your answer. The fact that it didn't work out with a String reference is another problem so I don't think you need to edit anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm... Actually my "solution" doesn't seem to work so great. I am having an EXC_BAD_ACCESS now. Still working on it...

Comment: It has EXC_BAD_ACCESS because the pointer memory is unallocated soon after it's use. I guess I would need to put it into a variable to keep it allocated, but I can't do that in my project.

Comment: Are you explicitly deallocating it or is swift doing so? Try using Deinitialization: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html

Answer (score 2):

For someone faced the same issue with me:

`Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from '' to '' requires a temporary`

The code as below:

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    var a: String{get set}
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {
    var a: String
    init(a: String) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

func update(foo: inout FooProtocol) {
    foo.a = "new string"
}

var f = Foo(a: "First String")
update(foo: &f)//Error: Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'Foo' to 'FooProtocol' requires a temporary
```

Change from `var f = Foo(a: "First String")` to `var f: FooProtocol = Foo(a: "First String")` fixed the Error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a class variable defined like this:

```
// file MyClass.swift

class MyClass{

    var myVariable:SomeClass!

    var otherVariable:OtherClass!

    ...

    func someFunction(){
        otherVariable.delegateFunction(parameter: &myVariable) // error
    }
}

// file OtherClass.swift
class OtherClass{
    func delegateFunction(parameter: inout myVariable){
        // modify myVariable's data members 
    }
}
```

There error that was invoked was:

```
Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'self' is immutable
```

I then changed my variable declaration in MyClass.swift to no longer have ! and instead initially point to some dummy instance of a class.

```
var myVariable:SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

My code was then able to compile and run as intended. So... somehow having the ! on a class variable prevents you from passing that variable as an inout variable. I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

For me i am passing the direct value in the function calling like this.

```
    public func testInout(_ a :  inout [Int]) -> Int {
        return a.reduce(0, +) 
    }

testInout(&[1,2,4]) // Getting the error :- Cannot pass immutable value of type '[Int]' as inout argument. Because by default the function parameters are constant.
```

To remove the above error you need the pass the array which has the var type. Like below.

```
 var arr = [1, 2, 3] 
   public func testInout(_ a :  inout [Int]) -> Int {
            return a.reduce(0, +) 
        }
    
    testInout(&arr)
```